# Connect SQL Server Profiler 2017 to Azure SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, azure

The title is pretty explicit, how can I connect my profiler to Azure?

So, I begin by opening the software, then a connect to my server:

[image]

However, I am getting this:

[image]

So I began to search what it could be and, I don't get it because, first `Max`is a `dbo_owner`... But anyway, from **Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio**, I then tried to grant the `ALTER TRACE` permission (*[you should take a look at this post](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3559/how-to-grant-permissions-to-run-sql-server-profiler-for-a-non-system-admin-user/)*)

```
GRANT ALTER TRACE TO Max
GO
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
Msg 40520, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Securable class 'server' not supported in this version of SQL Server.
```

Now, I just can't find the way to bypass this error. You could say "Update the server", Ok, but how?

Am I, at least, heading to the good direction in order to connect my profiler?

Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, the SQL Profiler is not available on Azure SQL. To do query profiling on Azure SQL, you can use [Dynamic Management Views](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/sql-database/sql-database-monitoring-with-dmvs#monitoring-query-performance) or take a look at the [Azure SQL Database Query Performance Insight](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-query-performance).

Answer (score 1):

Use "Azure Data Studio" with the "SQL Server Profiler" Extenstion. (see below MS links)

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/what-is?view=sql-server-ver15

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/sql-server-profiler-extension?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: I can confirm that with Azure Data Studio and the Profiler extension it's possible to profile Azure SQL DBs. Thanks!

Comment: But it still says no rights unless an admin logs in. So this is a catch-22 situation